# bootstrap 3 grid not side by side but below

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a forum that i found the code for online and i am customizing it. I'm using bootstrap 3, and inside the forum i want to have an 8 x 4 grid. I followed a tutorial but instead of placing it side by side the two divs are top and bottom

```
         <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">

          <div class="firstPost"
          <div class="postHeading">
            <h3>My shot, Banff Pano</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="postBody">
            <p>
            Here is a shot of Banff Alberta, Canada.
            I took a series of photographs in the portrait orientation 
and, using Lightroom and Photoshop, I stitched them together and 
adjusted the image to bring out more contrast and colors. The settings 
are f/11 at 1/500s; ISO 280.
          </p>
          <p>
            I'm wondering if I should have used a wider aperture and 
let the background be a little more blurred
          </p>
          </div>
          <div class="postImage">
            <img src="assets/banff.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="postFooter">
            <p>
              Posted on 7/23/15 at 12:05PM
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>


</div> <!-- end of 8 -->

<div class="col-md-4">

  <p>Something goes here</p>



</div>
</div> <!-- end of row -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are missing a closing tag `>` here

```
<div class="firstPost"
```

should be

```
<div class="firstPost">
```

Comment: I will vote your answer as the right one in 7 minutes (thats how long its making me wait).....thank you!